# ThinkingSphinx::ConnectionError asynchronous connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

My rails project running on server nginx + passenger. I noticed that thinking sphinx cannot respond to asynchronous connections. I run in two tabs on browser search query, and one of the responses returned this error:

```
Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol. Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol. Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) ...
```

thinking_sphinx.yml:

```
development:
  quiet_deltas: true
  mysql41: 9311
  bin_path: "/usr/bin"  
  searchd_binary_name: searchd
  indexer_binary_name: indexer
  min_infix_len: 3
  min_word_len: 2
  html_strip: 1
  index_exact_words: 1
  min_stemming_len: 4
  charset_type: "utf-8"
test:
  mysql41: 9311
production:
  mysql41: 9311
```

No such problems on localhost, server on WebRick.
What could I do, to avoid this. There is only one thinking-sphinx process. Maybe I can increase it's number.
Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I rebuilt thinking sphinx, I haven't done it for long time, now it doesn't     falling, maybe thing was in it. But I am still interested in how to run serveral ts processes, or it is unecessary.

Comment: add your sphinx config

Comment: I think you may need ot play with max_children config http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-max-children https://we.riseup.net/rails/running-a-sphinx-server

Answer (score 0):

Via the help [file](http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/common_issues.html#multiple)s:

You can run as many Sphinx instances as you wish on one machine - but each must be bound to a different port. You can do this via the config/thinking_sphinx.yml file - just add a setting for the port for the specific environment using the mysql41 setting (or port for pre-v3):

```
staging:
  mysql41: 9313
```

Comment: I couldn't get it. Should I write like:   mysql41: 9311,
  mysql41: 9312,
  mysql41: 9313
Or development:
  mysql41: 9311, development:
  mysql41: 9312, development:
  mysql41: 9313

Comment: And then, should I do rebuild, or restart will be enough?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have multiple searchd processes. Particular running on the same indexes. - Its for if want multiple TS instances running - as each will need a completely seperate searchd running.